# run JavaME codes directly from raspberrypi

Tags: java

As I understood and examined, you write a JavaME code on your computer and run it on RaspberryPi, is it possible to run your code directly from RaspberryPi or there always should be a computer to send it to RaspberryPi?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself ?

Comment: @dastaan acually thats a good idea, but javame library for RPi is in binary. also there is library called `pi4j` that do this, I wanted to know is it possible to do the same thing pi4j does with JavaME library

Answer (score 0):

You don't send the code to RPI. With Java ME what they advertise is remote development for headless setup, when you develop on PC, and then upload to RPI, where it RUNS DIRECTLY on RPI. you can compile your code on RPI as well, but IMHO running good IDE for Java development is a stretch for RPI. If you are up to use text editor for java files, you can totally edit/create files on RPI and compile it using javac on RPI without the need for PC. The only thing that Java ME provides on PC is ability to develop and test for RPI on PC with build-in emulator, so you can develop without access to RPI and then upload the final compiled code for execution on RPI.
So yes, you can edit and compile java ME directly on RPI, but you won't be able to efficiently use NetBeans or Eclipse IDE on RPI.